# Angular 2+ Observable - Check result in if statement

Tags: angular

Is it possible to check the result of an Observable in an if statement?

Something like:

```
if( this.loginsService.isAuthenticated().subscribe() == true ){
}
```

My LoginService:

```
  isAuthenticated(){
     return this.http.get('login/authenticated')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `subscribe` for the data

```
isAuthenticated():boolean{
     return this.http.get('login/authenticated')
      .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(data => return data);
  }
```

or you can put inside a local method and use that as below

```
isLoggedIn() :boolean{
   this.loginsService.isAuthenticated().subscribe(data => {
       return data; 
   });
 }

if(this.isLoggedIn() == true ){
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to simply return the result of an Observable, since Observables can't really be looked at as a single values.

### Change your method to return an Observable

```
isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> { // make the method return an Observable
    return this.http.get('login/authenticated')
      .map(res => res.json())
      .map(json => json.isAuthenticated) // get the value from the json, since you want a boolean
      .share(); // this will make it a hot observable. If you subscribe an observable that has not been "shared", it will make the HTTP call for every subscriber. sharing the observable will make it return the same value for that observable.
}
```

and the usage would involve subscribing to the observable:

```
export class AppComponent {
    isAuthenticated: boolean;

    constructor(private loginService: LoginService) {
        // you can save the value by subscribing once
        this.getIsAuthenticated().subscribe((isAuthenticated: boolean) => {
            this.isAuthenticated = isAuthenticated;
        };
    }

    getIsAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.loginService.isAuthenticated();
    }
}
```

or in the HTML:

```
<!-- use the Async pipe to get the value for you -->
<div *ngIf="getIsAuthenticated() | async">Im Authenticated!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It returns a `Subscription`, which will always be true as it's an `Object`.

So this will not work.  Do something like this instead.

```
this.loginsService.isAuthenticated().subscribe( isAuth => {
    if(isAuth) {
        //Take action
    }
})
```